# Evaluating limited stock when product modifier options are fractional

Tags: expresso-store

So I'm building an ecommerce site that sells items in the following quantities:

- Whole
- Half
- Quarter
- Eighth

The whole option is the default. So when they input the stock quantity (e.g. 100 whole items), I want that to mean that there are 200 half items, etc..

As a result, if someone orders 3 halves, I want the stock to be reduced to 98 whole and 1 half of that item.

Is there a way to do this in expresso store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to make the quantity represented as the smallest available fraction (e.g., 1/8), and make your quantity selector on the front-end reflect that. So if you had 100 whole items in inventory, you'd enter 800, then make a selection of "1" equal "8" on the front end.

Not ideal, but the only way I can see to do this with Store's inventory system.

Comment: That or a custom extension would be needed